# Missing mysql_install_db on CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos

I've been given access to a server running CentOS 5.4 to install some software on and it looks like mysql needs setting up. The problem is that it I can't find `mysql_install_db` (which I think is what I need to run as there's no mysql folder in `/var/lib/`).

According to yum, both `mysql` and `mysql-server` packages are installed. Looking at another CentOS 5.4 machine I have setup, it looks like it's apart of the `mysql-server` package, but it ain't there on this machine. Running this...

```
rpm -ql mysql-server | grep mysql_install_db
```

Gives me nothing at all on the machine I need to setup (and locates it fine on my correctly working machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have original distro mysql-server there. Because running "rpm -ql mysql-server" on a clean Centos box shows both mysql_install_db and /var/lib/mysql as parts of the package.

Comment: hmmm I see. I guess it might need reinstalling then.